# Does convergence in $L^2$ imply convergence on $\mathbb R$?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, inner-products

On the very first page of my textbook's Hilbert spaces chapter I've found the following statement:

> Let $(V,\langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle)$ be an inner product space. 
>   $(v_j)_{j\in\mathbb N}\subset V$.
>
> $$\lim_{j\rightarrow \infty} v_j=v\iff \lim_{j\rightarrow \infty}
>  \|v_j-v\|=0$$

Now, we know that $L^2_{\mathbb R}$ is a inner product space (a complete one), with norm defined by

$$\|u\|=\|u\|_2=\bigg(\int u^2d\mu\bigg)^{1/2}$$

Hence the previous statement reads

For $(v_j)_{j\in\mathbb N}\subset L^2_{\mathbb R}(\mu)$

$$\lim_{j\rightarrow \infty} v_j=v\iff \lim_{j\rightarrow \infty}
 \|v_j-v\|_2=0$$

Namely, the sequence converges pointwise iff it converges in $L^2$-sense.

But, if I am not mistaken in general point-wise convergence does not guarantee convergence in $L^2$.

Conversely if the sequence converges in $L^2$ I can say that there's a subsequence converging a.e. in $\mathbb R$.

Is this a particular property of $L^2$ spaces?
 Am I missing something?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I missing something?

Yes. The notation $\lim_{j \to \infty} v_j = v$ says nothing about pointwise convergence. It simply is a notation for the statement that $v_j$ converges to $v$ in $L^2$, which *by definition* means $\|v_j - v\|_2 \to 0$.

Comment: (+1) Yes.  And that is the end of the story.   Good to see you're back.

Comment: I see, so it's simply a matter of notation. I get confused because in general to imply convergence in $L^p$ the author always used $L^p-lim$ while $lim$ was used in general for pointwise convergence.

Comment: Unfortunately different authors will use different notation for the same things, and the same notation for different things. It helps to pay close attention to the context.